# How can I make the Rotation property easier to edit on the Graph Editor?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, graph-editor

First time trying to animate in Blender.

Im animating something spinning 720 degrees and my Graph Editor looks like this zoomed all the way out to accomodate the keyframes for the Z Rotation.

[image: Zoomed out Graph Editor]

It's really hard to see and i can't accurately click the bezier handles even when zoomed in. All my other keyframes are small at the bottom

[image: Zoomed in Graph Editor]

Here it is zoomed in to the other keyframes but now I can't see my Z rotation ones. I'm used to the After Effects graph editor where it proportionally scales the graph editor depending on the values for that property. How can i do something similar for Blender? Sorry I don't know how to word this question to google it!

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think (AFAIK) that it is possible to have different scales at the same time in one graph. You can zoom to one of it  - of course - but the downside is then, that you might not the the other graphs at the same time. Maybe a solution for you might be to open two graph editors at the same time with different graphs zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag mouse on the axis indicator on the right of the dope sheet to scale the view across only the Y axis. It's a little clumsy but it should allow you to see your handles better.

[image]

apologies for my ugly arrows.

Comment: Hi @ruckus I'm the OP (Olivia) but i forgot the login to my account, and this one is too new to upvote or reply to your answer but that's helped for me, sorry for the slow reply!

Comment: Hey no problem im here to help. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) might help with your account problem.